# SimpleDateFormat: unparseable date exception with correct pattern

Tags: java, date

I have simple code, it still throws me `unparseable date exception`. I'm confused, the pattern seems to be correct.

```
DateFormat dffrom = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
dffrom.parse("Sun Jan 20 00:50:24 CET 2013");
```

I tried also these patterns:

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z YYYY"
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz YYYY"
```

Comment: I found threads with similar problem, I tried accepted code and it also throws me expception. It don't make sense :(

Comment: I tried it in Holland and over here it needs to be "Zo Jan 20 00:50:24 CET 2013"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your default `Locale` may not recognize the words "Sun" and/or "Jan". Try with `ENGLISH` `Locale`:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

To view your default `Locale` you can use:

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

See: [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

Comment: yees, I'm fool, I absolutelly forgot on it. Thanks. Why is Locale optional param?

Comment: It's optional to allow you to specify a Locale other than the default one, just like in this case.

Comment: ok, how can i retrieve my default locale? When I use new Date(), it returns me date in the above format.

Comment: @Reimeus Why are you passing a Locale? There is a constructor without Locale. I don't think this is the most accurate answer.

Comment: @sfrj The OP is getting a parse exception. His default locale may be the source of the error.

Comment: @sfrj The String you're supplying is written in English, so you have to tell the parser that it should use an English parser. If you don't provide a Locale, it'll parse using your default locale.

Comment: What is the difference among ENGLISH and US?

Comment: AFAIK `en_US` is a country/region variant of `ENGLISH`, which is why both `Locales` will work here.

Comment: Thanks. `UK` and `US` have difference in position of day number, but i don't notice any difference between `US` and `ENGLISH`.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your Locale.

```
DateFormat dffrom = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

will work.